# PowerShell "select as" function on variable

Tags: powershell, select, alias

This is just a simple question regarding alias issue on PowerShell syntax. Yet I can't find any related solution to it ATM.

```
Select SystemName , DeviceID,
```

From the above statement, I would like to display

> "DeviceID" as "drives"

and

> "SystemName" as "server"

Whole PowerShell script for ref:

```
$diskvalue += Get-WmiObject @Params | Select SystemName , DeviceID, @{Name=”size(MB)”;Expression={“{0:N1}” -f($_.size/1mb)}}, @{Name=”freespace(MB)”;Expression={“{0:N1}” -f($_.freespace/1mb)}}, @{Name=”UsedSpace(MB)”;Expression={“{0:N2}” -f(($_.size - $_.FreeSpace)/1mb)}}
    $diskvalue | Export-Csv C:\example.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select @{l='drives';e='DeviceID'}, @{l='server';e='SystemName'}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. but i tried replace it, appear to be error. I add the whole powershell script for reference.

Comment: @D.chan what error? `Get-WmiObject Win32_logicaldisk | Select SystemName , DeviceID, @{Name=”size(MB)”;Expression={“{0:N1}” -f($_.size/1mb)}}, @{Name=”freespace(MB)”;Expression={“{0:N1}” -f($_.freespace/1mb)}}, @{Name=”UsedSpace(MB)”;Expression={“{0:N2}” -f(($_.size - $_.FreeSpace)/1mb)}}` works fine

Comment: Missing expression after ','.
At C:\ ps1:31 char:91
+     $diskvalue += Get-WmiObject @Params | Select @{l='drives';e='DeviceID'}, @{l='server', <<<< e='SystemName'}, @{Name=”size(MB)”;Expression={“{0:N1}” -f($_.size/1mb)}}, @{Name=”freespace(MB)”;Expression={“{0:N1}” -f($_.
freespace/1mb)}}, @{Name=”UsedSpace(MB)”;Expression={“{0:N2}” -f(($_.size - $_.FreeSpace)/1mb)}}
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (,:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken

Comment: i found out the issue. it should be
select @{l='drives';e='DeviceID'}, @{l='server';e='SystemName'}
";" instead of ","